# Does https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations support ASP.NET Core 2?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, expressiveannotations

Using NuGet Package Manager I installed this: https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations. However, VS2017 reported conflict as package requires .net 4.6.1 framework. Does this package support the ASP.NET Core 2 framework?